# why do we need the ioc container

Tags: spring, ioc-container

Hi:
I ask this question not for cheating your attention.

Since our team begin to use spring,but I really can not understand why we should use a container,I know it do the object creating job for us,but is this the very reason?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I need an IoC container as opposed to straightforward DI code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871405/why-do-i-need-an-ioc-container-as-opposed-to-straightforward-di-code)