# Ninject IoC Project website

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I know this question has no related code to be written, but I am planning on using Ninject IoC and I was trying to visit [www.ninject.org](http://www.ninject.org/), however the webpage is not available.

Has this project been discontinued? I just want to know if i should look at different technologies such as [Autofac](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/index.html), [Castle Windsor](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx) or [Unity](https://unity.codeplex.com/) before I start building my project.

Comment: It has not been discountinued. Development takes places on [github](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/). Just a few days back a pull request was merged. Most documentation is available [here](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki)

Comment: [Ninject is definitely the slowest container](http://www.palmmedia.de/blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison)

Comment: @qujck you may be right about Ninject, but you have to remember that that comparison was done a few years ago. Things could have changed in their newer versions.

Comment: @Komengem this post has been actively maintained since it first appeared, as is the [source code](https://github.com/danielpalme/IocPerformance) and the versions of the containers being tested. Last updated to the website was 2nd Jan 2015 (scroll to the bottom of the post just before the comments).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DNS just had to be updated. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

*In reaction to the perf comment... While we're stuffing in bad primary selection criteria for containers, I thought I'd interject with what came to my mind:*

I'd like to point out that [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) is a very important alternative to consider, whic is gaining momentum.

From personal experience I can say  that DI done wrong, aided and abetted by a Container (or three) and some Architect[ure Austronauts] is a scary thing.

Even when use of a DI container is done consciously, the stuff it hides and important feedback that's supressed by containers is not to be underestimated. On the other had, it's very easy to overestimate a few hundred lines of code reduction after a hard fougt battle (eiter politically or techincally) to have a container introduced. An excellent presentation discussing some of this is Greg Yougn's [8 lines of code](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/8-lines-code-refactoring).

Consider joining the ABC:- Anti-Container Brigade :P

Comment: Not sure your basis for the claim "gaining momentum" but +1 for being right about the rest. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871405/why-do-i-need-an-ioc-container-as-opposed-to-straightforward-di-code)'s a question from a few years ago on this very topic. You'll notice [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/871420/1515209) that [Joel Spolsky](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky) has been opposed to the idea of a container for a very long time :-)

Comment: @qujck Yes, needless to say, there is no evidence whatsoever, and obviously there are all sorts of leaing/trailing effects :) As for whether JS called it, I'd don't buy that - all his arguments were on a general Archtecture Astronautery basis which is fine but not concerete (just like the RCM baiting, which was for me was based in poplist ranting rathe than any material position based on any deep understanding - or at least that's the feel the relevant SO podcasts left me with).