# How to get factory pattern to work between projects?

Tags: c#, winforms, factory-pattern

I have the following 3 projects.

Services:
In this project I have a number of "service" classes and the following factory class:

```
public class ServiceFactory : IServiceFactory
{
    public TService Get<TEntity, TService>()
        where TEntity : class
        where TService : IService<TEntity>
    {
        object[] args = new object[] { };

        return (TService)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TService), args);
    }
}
```

A service interface looks like this:

```
public interface ICustomerService : IService<Customer>
{
    IEnumerable<Customer> GetAll();
}
```

Main:
The main project implements the services defined in the above project, eg:

```
public class CustomerService : ICustomerService
{
    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetAll()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Plugins
This project contains plugins and each plugin can use one or more different services. The plugins are loaded using `MEF`. A plugin might look like this:

```
[Export(typeof(IPlugin))]
public class CustomerPlugin : IPlugin
{
    private readonly ICustomerService customerService;

    public CustomerPlugin (IServiceFactory serviceFactory)
    {
        customerService = serviceFactory.Get<Customer, CustomerService>();
    }
}
```

Plugins are loaded and created within the main project.

However there is a problem in the above code (in the Plugins project) because the serviceFactory tries to create a concrete implementation, ie. CustomerService, but this is obviously not possible because it's only available in the Main project.

How is it possible to get this factory pattern working?

Comment: Do you use an [IoC container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871405/why-do-i-need-an-ioc-container-as-opposed-to-straightforward-di-code)?

Comment: @JohnWu Not in the WinForms Main project. I assume I need to use Autofac there as well.